# Xamarin.Forms iOS app in Release mode Community Toolkit TouchEffect command not firing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with an Android and iOS version. The Android version is working fine in both Debug and Release mode.. in fact the Android version is already in the Play Store.

However the iOS version has an odd issue. In debug mode it works perfectly, however in Release mode everywhere I use the Xamarin Toolkit TouchEffect in order to attach a Command to an element, does not fire.

```
<buttons:BackButton xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BackCommand}" xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True" />
```

I looked online and apparently this could be a linker issue since maybe the linker is stripping this code from the final build, however I have it set to "Link Framework SDKs only" which seems to be the recommended setting when publishing your app.

[image]

Is there something else I may be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a lot of research indeed the bug is with the linker, which is stripping some Community Toolkit code from the release build, despite the fact that I am using the toolkit in xaml. One thing to note is that I'm only using the toolkit in Xaml.

By simply creating a class in the iOS project file with the below code, the linker sees that I indeed need this package and doesn't strip it's code.

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Effects.TouchEffect arg)
    {
        var dummyCommand = arg.Command;
        var dummyCommandParameter = arg.CommandParameter;
        var dummyNativeAnimation = arg.NativeAnimation;
    }
}
```

Edit: this may not be enough to solve the issue. If it still persists, try include ‘--linkskip=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit’ inside Additional mtouch arguments of iOS Build screen. That should do it.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue but this solution didn't solve the problem.
I'm using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 and XCT: 1.2.0

Comment: Try include ‘--linkskip=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit’ inside Additional mtouch arguments of iOS Build screen. I did this plus what I wrote in my post simultaneously so not sure which is actually the fix of the two.

Comment: Thank you so much for this last tip and I'm sorry for this delayed gratitude.
At that moment, I setted No link and that resolved the problem.
But now, when I have to submit a new version to the AppStore this problem come back.
This last tip that you mention was the key to complete the initial solution.
THANKS again.

Comment: I think you should edit your own answer and include the builder arguments to help ohters...

Comment: I'm glad that solved it for you! I've added that tip in my post and ticked to solve so others will know this is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this issue on Android platform we can fix it by adding `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit;` in "Ignore Assemblies" Entry in "Android Build -> Linker" section.
For some reason when we keep Linker Behaviour as "Don't link" then also not taking these assemblies.